# Migrating from static hosting to the cloud!

Tags: php, hosting, amazon-s3, cloud, new-operator

So unfortunately I'm a newbie to the application (web) development world. While I did graduate with a CS degree its theory funness hasn't helped out much. However I am trying to jump in feet first. My php application I build is simply sitting on a cheap hosting provider. In order to launch it I'd like to it to be able to scale well (fun buzz word).

However, as I said I'm totally new to it and I suck at git.

So as I've read I'm looking to host the mySql database and the php files on phpfog, my css and images on amazon S3, and then the email server as Amazon SES?

Is this the right frame of mind, and/or will this handle a flurry of (hoped for) traffic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of scaling in mind for just starting out. Keep it simple. Google Apps Standard gives you 10 accounts to work with, and you can a nice GMail interface as a bonus.

Keep your hosting simple for now, you don't need Amazon S3 for CSS and images yet. Silver pricing seems decent for just starting out at PHPFog. Remember you can always increase capacity later on.

Before you say "flurry of traffic", make sure you have a solid business plan. How will you market your product/service? Who are your competitors? What differentiates your product/service? Pretend like you're pitching this to a VC firm.

If you don't have a solid plan to work with, you're throwing too much money at infrastructure that you won't be using.

Comment: Lets say I'm awesome and this is already done (the b-plan, monetization strategies etc.). I'm just trying to learn what would be the best option to go with, if all does go well. From what I understand PHPFog doesn't do well with images/css and such. So I figured putting them on Amazon would be the best bet, I'd love some suggestions as to a better/cheaper/easier alternative.

Comment: @William Then if you've got funding and everything, hire/contract a seasoned systems admin to help you figure out exactly what you need given requirements. If you're serious about your business, this is the way to go.

Comment: I've got a plan, vision, and hope but not funding! (The awesome part, was a bit tongue in cheek) I'd like to learn a bit in the process before I go hire someone to do my work for me. So I'm more interested in doing this myself, as it seems possible with a push in the right direction! @onteria_ thanks though for the ideas!

Comment: @William, yes, as @onteria_ said: "If you are awesome -- just hire someone, who understand it best and do the business".

Comment: Hmmm I never thought that "just hire someone " was the best way to learn!

Comment: @William It is because you have someone to ask questions to and learn from when you're not sure how to go about something.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn about the technical aspects of the infrastructure you're choosing, you probably should begin by learning about how it works. http://media.amazonwebservices.com/AWS_Cloud_Best_Practices.pdf
 will give you a nice overview on how scaling works on AWS and the cloud in general.